# Compilation Error on Recursive Variadic Template Function

Tags: c++, recursion, c++11, codeblocks, variadic

I've prepared a simple variadic template test in Code::Blocks, but I'm getting an error:

> No matching function for call to 'OutputSizes()'

Here's my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template <typename FirstDatatype, typename... DatatypeList>
void OutputSizes()
{
    std::cout << typeid(FirstDatatype).name() << ": " << sizeof(FirstDatatype) << std::endl;
    OutputSizes<DatatypeList...>();
}

int main()
{
    OutputSizes<char, int, long int>();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using GNU GCC with `-std=C++0x`.  Using `-std=gnu++0x` makes no difference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's how you disambiguate the base case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename FirstDatatype>
void OutputSizes()
{
    std::cout << typeid(FirstDatatype).name() << ": " << sizeof(FirstDatatype) << std::endl;
}

template <typename FirstDatatype, typename SecondDatatype, typename... DatatypeList>
void OutputSizes()
{
    OutputSizes<FirstDatatype>()
    OutputSizes<SecondDatatype, DatatypeList...>();
}

int main()
{
    OutputSizes<char, int, long int>();
}
```

Comment: I wonder if this is possible to make work without having a three-argument version of the template?

Comment: The three argument OutputSizes should call the single argument one to reduce code duplication.

Comment: Doug Gregor (the main force behind variadic templates) has recently submitted a core issue in this area.  I am not knowledgable enough to know if it impacts or changes this use case or not (sorry).  The issue has not yet been assigned a number so I can not point you to it.

Comment: I thought at first that the second template could be `<typename FirstDatatype, typename... DatatypeList>`, and that partial ordering would solve the ambiguity with the call to `OutputSizes<char>`, but partial ordering won't be able to resolve that since there are no function parameters :( @Howard, did he post that issue to the core list somewhere? Note that this is not specific to variadic templates. For instance `template<typename T> void f(); template<typename T, typename U = void> void f();` and then a call to `f<int>` is similarly ambiguous, I think.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you didn't provide a base case. You extracted the last data type of the variadic template parameter- then you tried to match an empty variadic parameter to a function taking a type and a variadic parameter. You need to provide a "base case" for when the variadic parameter is empty.

```
using namespace std;

template <typename FirstDatatype, typename... DatatypeList>
void OutputSizes()
{
    std::cout << typeid(FirstDatatype).name() << ": " << sizeof(FirstDatatype) << std::endl;
    OutputSizes<DatatypeList...>();
}

template<typename... DataTypeList>
void OutputSizes() // We're called when there's no template arguments
                   // left in the pack
{
}

int main()
{
    OutputSizes<char, int, long int>();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: The many-zero overloads I have shown here actually only work when you take actual run-time arguments too based on the template types. If you only take template parameters directly, you have use two-one recursion like shown in Howard Hinnant's answer.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but could you provide an example?  I tried overloading it with just `template <typename Datatype>` but got ambiguous overload errors.

Comment: @Maxpm: I'm not an expert on variadic templates, as my compiler doesn't support them, but I believe that the above should compile.

Comment: I think using the term 'base class' here is confusing. Perhaps 'recursion termination condition' would be better.

Comment: I can't get the above to compile. Could you make sure it works?

Comment: This code does not compile: "ambiguous call to overloaded function". Tried with 3 different compilers.