# recursive variadic template to print out the contents of a parameter pack

Tags: recursion, c++11, variadic-templates, typeid

How is it possible to create a recursive variadic template to print out the contents of a paramater pack?
I am trying with this, but it fails to compile:

```
template <typename First, typename ...Args>
std::string type_name () {
    return std::string(typeid(First).name()) + " " + type_name<Args...>();
}
std::string type_name () {
    return "";
}
```

How shall I end the recursion?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to use partial specialisation to end the recursion, but since you can't partially specialise free functions in C++, you need to create an implementation class with a static member function.

```
template <typename... Args>
struct Impl;

template <typename First, typename... Args>
struct Impl<First, Args...>
{
  static std::string name()
  {
    return std::string(typeid(First).name()) + " " + Impl<Args...>::name();
  }
};

template <>
struct Impl<>
{
  static std::string name()
  {
    return "";
  }
};

template <typename... Args>
std::string type_name()
{
    return Impl<Args...>::name();
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << type_name<int, bool, char, double>() << std::endl; // "i b c d"
  return 0;
}
```

That first declaration of `Impl` is just [a workaround for a shortcoming in g++ 4.6](http://poita.org/index.php/blog/1-latest-news/53-using-c0x-variadic-templates-with-g) (and below). It won't be necessary once it implements variadic templates correctly.

[Check it out in action at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/jjmCc)

Comment: The workaround link you cite is dead. Can you elaborate the correct way to do this without a buggy g++?

Comment: Although this answer is correct, it is outdated. A simpler approach is possible, see other answers.

Comment: This technique also works when the template arguments are templates (variadic template consisting of template template arguments)

Answer (score 50):

There's actually a very elegant way to end the recursion:

```
template <typename Last>
std::string type_name () {
    return std::string(typeid(Last).name());
}

template <typename First, typename Second, typename ...Rest>
std::string type_name () {
    return std::string(typeid(First).name()) + " " + type_name<Second, Rest...>();
}
```

I initially tried `template <typename Last>` and `template <typename First, typename ...Rest>` but that was considered ambiguous (Rest can be zero elements). This question then showed me the definitive solution: [Compilation Error on Recursive Variadic Template Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035889/compilation-error-on-recursive-variadic-template-function)

---

Note, to avoid a bit of code duplication, you could also do:

```
template <typename Last>
std::string type_name () {
    return std::string(typeid(Last).name());
}

template <typename First, typename Second, typename ...Rest>
std::string type_name () {
    return type_name<First>() + " " + type_name<Second, Rest...>();
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if the parameter pack is empty, but otherwise a very nice solution.

Comment: just add a 3rd overload for the empty case (if you want one)

Comment: I'd personally use this solution but, for completeness' sake, C++11 allows you to use `std::enable_if` to specify that you only want the variadic case matched if there are more than two arguments:

`typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Rest) >= 1, int>::type = 0`

Answer (score 32):

C++17's `if constexpr` allows you to do this in one template declaration which is, unlike a lot of the older solutions, pretty easy to understand:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
std::string type_name() {
  if constexpr (!sizeof...(Args)) {
    return std::string(typeid(T).name());
  } else {
    return std::string(typeid(T).name()) + " " + type_name<Args...>();
  }
}
```

Comment: IMO this answer should be a little higher up

Answer (score 12):

As an alternative to non-existing partial specialization for functions, you can use overloading on a typifier class:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <unsigned int N> struct NumberToType { };

template <typename T>
std::string my_type_name(NumberToType<0> = NumberToType<0>())
{
  return std::string(typeid(T).name());
}

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
std::string my_type_name(NumberToType<sizeof...(Args)> = NumberToType<sizeof...(Args)>())
{
  return std::string(typeid(T).name()) + " " + my_type_name<Args...>(NumberToType<sizeof...(Args)-1>());
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << my_type_name<int, double, char>() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative, you can unpack the parameter pack in-place as in the following example:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
std::string type_name () {
    std::string str = typeid(T).name();
    int arr[] = { 0, (str += std::string{" "} + typeid(Args).name(), 0)... };
    (void)arr;
    return str;
}

int main() {
    auto str = type_name<int, double, char>();
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Recursion is not required actually to do that.

Comment: compilation error due `constexpr` function declaration (VS2015 Update 3). All will compile, if it will be removed

Comment: @skypkack, i compile with `/std:c++latest` , i.e. supports `C++17`. Errors are:
`Error C3250 'str': declaration is not allowed in 'constexpr' function body ` and `Error C3250 'arr': declaration is not allowed in 'constexpr' function body `

Comment: @Macias nothing special, this is the pre-C++17 alternative to fold expressions. It unrolls the parameter pack and _does things_.

Comment: @skypjack Its nice :) You can event write the body of your function like this: `return ( std::string(typeid(Args).name() + std::string(" ")) + ...);` You should then remove first template parameter T.

Comment: It only works with C++17 - working example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/JEXUzCZbub57OFyy (I can't edit previous comment)

Comment: @Macias yep, but the Q/A is from 2016. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack Right, but You could update your answer with a solution from c ++ 17 as a curiosity :)

Answer (score 5):

Use C++17 fold expression:

```
template <typename ...Args>
std::string type_name () {
    return (std::string(typeid(Args).name()) + " " + ...);
}
```