# Does new line character also flush the buffer?

Tags: c++, flush, endl

I understand that questions like, *difference between `endl` and `\n`* have been answered many times on SO. But they only mention that `endl` is able to flush the buffer onto the `stdout`, while `\n`, does not.

So, what I understand by buffer being flushed is that, the input given is stored in a buffer, and is passed onto the `stdout` only when it comes across `endl`, or some explict `flush` functions. If so, I expected that the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Hello\nworld";
    sleep(2);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

To display:

*After 2 seconds*

```
Hello
World
```

But the actual output was:

```
Hello
```

*After 2 seconds*

```
World
```

Why is it so ?

shouldn't `\n` also be stored in the buffer and only when `endl` is encountered buffer is to be flushed/displayed onto the `stdout`, but from what I observe `\n` is acting the same way as `endl`.

Comment: It depends on where `cout` is going.  If it goes to a terminal ('interactive device'), then it can't be fully buffered — it is usually line buffered, meaning that characters appear after a newline is printed, or could in theory be unbuffered.  If it is going to a pipe or file or other non-interactive destination, the `endl` forces the data out even if the stream is fully buffered, as it usually will be.

Comment: I also wanted to know if I provided neither new line character nor `endl` , will the output be displayed on the `stdout` once it reaches the end of the program, I know it does for terminal, but is it applicable to all types of `stdout`?

Comment: Yes, when the file stream is closed at the (normal) end of the program, pending output will be flushed.  It'll also be flushed when the buffer is full.  If the program aborts, pending output usually won't be flushed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: the C++ way to deal with output to interactive streams is to have `std::cin` be `tie()`d to `std::cout`: whenever `std::cin` is accessed, `std::cout` is flushed. The actual reason line buffer behaviour is observed for C++ programs writing to `stdout` is the synchronization with stdio which is, obviously, disabled for any sane C++ program using standard streams as the program is otherwise unreasonably slowed down.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer.*</sup>

It depends on where `cout` is going. If it goes to a terminal ('interactive device'), then it can't be fully buffered — it is usually line buffered, meaning that characters appear after a newline is printed, or could in theory be unbuffered. If it is going to a pipe or file or other non-interactive destination, the `endl` forces the data out even if the stream is fully buffered, as it usually will be.

> I also wanted to know if I provided neither new line character nor `endl`, will the output be displayed on the `stdout` once it reaches the end of the program, I know it does for terminal, but is it applicable to all types of `stdout`?

Yes, when the file stream is closed at the (normal) end of the program, pending output will be flushed. It'll also be flushed when the buffer is full. If the program aborts, pending output usually won't be flushed.

Answer (score 7):

The default setup for the standard C++ stream objects (`std::cin`, `std::cout`, `std::cerr`, and `std::clog`) is that they are synchronized with the corresponding C streams (`stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`). Synchronization means that alternating access of the C++ and the C streams results in consistent behaviour. For example, this code is expected to produce the string `hello, world`:

```
std::cout << "hel";
fprintf(stdout, "lo,");
std::cout << " wo";
fprintf(stdout, "rld");
```

The C++ standard makes no mandate on how this synchronization is implemented. One way to implement it is to disable any buffering for `std::cout` (and family) and immediately access `stdout`. That is, the above example could immediately write the individual characters to `stdout`.

If the characters are actually written to `stdout` the default setting for the buffering mode for `stdout` would be used. I can't find a specification in the standard but typically the default for the buffering mode of `stdout` is `_IOLBF` when it is connected to an interactive stream (e.g., a console), i.e., the buffer is flushed at the end of lines. The default for writing to a file is typically `_IOFBF`, i.e., the output is flushed when a complete buffer is written. As a result, writing a newline to `std::cout` could result in the buffer being flushed.

The streams in C++ are normally set up to be buffered. That is, writing a newline to a file will generally not cause the output to appear immediately (it would only appear immediately if the character caused the buffer to overflow the stream is set to be unbuffered). Since the synchronization with `stdout` is often unnecessary, e.g., when a program always uses `std::cout` to write to the standard output, but does cause output to the standard output to be slowed down quite dramatically (disabling buffering for stream makes them **slow**) the synchronization can be disabled:

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

This disables synchronization for all stream objects. For a bad implementation there could be no effect while a good implementation will enable buffering for `std::cout` resulting in a substantial speed-up and probably also disabling line buffering.

Once a C++ stream is buffered, there is no built-in way to cause it to be flushed when a newline is written. The primary reason for this is that dealing with line buffering would require inspection of each character by the stream buffer which effectively inhibits bulk operations on characters and thereby causing a substantial slow-down. If needed, line buffering can be implemented through a simple filtering stream buffer. For example:

```
class linebuf: public std::streambuf {
    std::streambuf* sbuf;
public:
    linebuf(std::streambuf* sbuf): sbuf(sbuf) {}
    int_type overflow(int_type c) {
        int rc = this->sbuf->sputc(c);
        this->sbuf->pubsync();
        return rc;
    }
    int sync() { return this->sbuf->pubsync(); }
};
// ...
int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    linebuf sbuf(std::cout.rdbuf());
    std::streambuf* origcout = std::cout.rdbuf(&sbuf);

    std::cout << "line\nbuffered\n";

    std::cout.rdbuf(origcout); // needed for clean-up;
}
```

tl;dr: the C++ standard doesn't have a concept of line buffering but it may get it when standard I/O is synchronized from C's behaviour of `stdout`.