# Comparing A Character To Characters Inside Of A String In C++

Tags: c++, compare, character

I'm trying to compare two characters (my search character, and the characters in an input string) to see how many of my search characters are present in the given string. But, all I am getting for the count is 0, no matter what I input.

Below is my code for reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    int length = 0;
    char ch;
    char search;
    int count = 0;

    length = str.length();

    cin >> search;
    cin >> str;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        //current character
        ch = str[i];
        //cout << ch << " ";
        if (ch == search) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    cout << count << " " << search << "'s" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried both `ch.compare(search)` and `(ch == search)`, as seen in my code. Both just result in me getting 0 for `count`. I've also flipped `ch` and `search`, and tried to set both `search` and `ch` to `' '`, but again none of it did anything. Example of one of the tests I've tried is below.

> How many `e`'s are in the string `"Geek"`.

I don't know what I am doing wrong, as all I'm getting as the output is 0 for `count`.

For example:

Input: `"Geek"`
Wanted Output: `2 e's`
What I'm getting: `0 e's`

I'm using CLion for my IDE, with my Language Standard set at C++23.

Comment: *How many e's are in the string "Geek"* -- `std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), 'e');`

Comment: C++ isn't a spreadsheet. `length = str.length();` sets `length` to 0, because that's the length of `str` at that point in the code. Later changes to `str` don't change `length`. You have to set `length` again after `str` changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are retrieving the value of `str.length()` **before** you have read the user's input into `str`. `str` is still empty at that time, and so your `length` variable is always 0, thus your loop never runs.

You need to read the `str.length()` value **after** you have read in the input into `str`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    int length = 0;
    char ch;
    char search;
    int count = 0;

    // length = str.length(); // <-- too early here!

    cin >> search;
    cin >> str;

    length = str.length(); // <-- move it here instead!

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        //current character
        ch = str[i];
        //cout << ch << " ";
        if (ch == search) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    cout << count << " " << search << "'s" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/TmCKk8)

That being said, you can eliminate the need for reading the `length` at all by using iterators instead of indexes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    char ch;
    char search;
    int count = 0;

    cin >> search;
    cin >> str;

    for (auto iter = str.begin(); iter != str.end(); ++iter) {

        //current character
        ch = *iter;
        //cout << ch << " ";
        if (ch == search) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    cout << count << " " << search << "'s" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/1ZIqiH)

Or, by using a [range-for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) (which uses iterators internally):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    char search;
    int count = 0;

    cin >> search;
    cin >> str;

    for (char ch : str) {
        //cout << ch << " ";
        if (ch == search) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    cout << count << " " << search << "'s" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/qcZ0Pl)

Or, by using the standard [`std::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) algorithm instead of a manual loop at all:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    char search;
    int found;

    cin >> search;
    cin >> str;

    found = count(str.begin(), str.end(), search);

    cout << found << " " << search << "'s" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/fnkqOU)

Comment: You know what, it looks like you know your stuff, so you earned my upvote. However, I would suggest changing endl into '\n' as endl flushes the stream.

Comment: @Hudson [Does new line character also flush the buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430701/does-new-line-character-also-flush-the-buffer)

Comment: Oh well, I was told that endl is bad and \n is better.

Comment: Thanks, moving it worked. I hadn't realized I had my length() in the wrong position. Also, thanks for showing me two different ways I could also solve my problem.