# Using variadic templates for chains of templated classes to generate serialization

Tags: c++, qt, templates, variadic-templates, template-templates

I have an eager project in which I try to enable serialization of structs as effortlessly as possible by writing something along the lines of this:

```
class Data {
  const QString& string();
  void setString(QString string);
  ...
};

const QString stringName() { return "string"; }

template class <class Invokee, typename ContentType, const QString(*NameFunction)(), const ContentType& (Invokee::* Getter)() const> Field;

void serialize() {
  Data data{...};
  QJsonObject serialized 
    = serialize<Data, Field1, Field2, ...>;
}
```

which should output a json object. I recently found out there are variadic templates in c++ and was very excited to see if I could define such a Serializer template that takes an arbitrary amount of Fields and then serializes them. However I was stuck at the following code:

```
template<
    class Invokee,
    typename ContentType,
    const QString(*NameFunction)(),
    const ContentType& (Invokee::* Getter)() const
    >
void serializeToObject(QJsonObject& object, const Invokee& invokee) {
  auto name = NameFunction();

  object[name] = (invokee.*Getter)();
}


template<
      class Invokee,
      template<
          class,
          typename ContentType,
          const QString(*)(),
          const ContentType& (Invokee::* Getter)() const
          > class Field,
      class FieldClass,
      class FieldInvokee,
      typename FieldContentType,
      const QString(*FieldNameFunction)(),
      const FieldContentType& (Invokee::* FieldGetter)() const,

      class... Args
      >
void serializeToObject(QJsonObject& object, const Invokee& invokee) {
  serializeToObject<FieldInvokee, FieldContentType, FieldNameFunction, FieldGetter>(object, invokee);

  serializeToObject<Invokee, Args...>(object, invokee);
}
```

This appears to compile but I have not yet been able to get it to work in practice. Namely I am trying to use it like this:

```
void tryOut() {
  Data data;
  data.setString("testString");
  QJsonObject object{};

  serializeToObject
      <
      Data,
      Field<Data, QString, stringName, &Data::string>
      >
  (object, testClass);
}
```

Compiler complains that my call to stringName is ill-formed. Despite that a test instantiation of Field<...> seems to work, the call to the function does not with error code:

```
candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'NameFunction'
void serializeToObject(QJsonObject& object, Invokee& invokee) {
```

I'm scratching my head as to what I'm doing wrong or if this is possible at all.

Comment: [OT]: returning const object is useless (and even worse as it forbid some optimisations).

Comment: You might be interested by `BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT` or equivalent. (As you use Qt, [Q_PROPERTY](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) might help).

Comment: Why don't use ready-made serialization libraries, such as [cereal](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/index.html) ?

Comment: @Jarod42 you mean in the constant field naming function? Do you have an article on that? I'd love to read it up.

Comment: @VladimirBershov Well an additional library is always one more to keep track of. But I can see how someone would use it if that weren't a problem.

Comment: @PandaOnsen14: [tutorial example of boost hana](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-introspection-json) to build a json. `Q_PROPERTY` also allows to have introspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but the right tool isn't template templates. To dig into type parameters, like you want to do by extracting all the template parameters of `Field`, you need to use partial template specialization.

Since this can all be simplified a bit in C++17, I'm going to split this into two:

#### C++11 Solution

To start, simplify `Field` so it's a regular template:

```cpp
template <
    class Invokee, 
    typename ContentType, 
    const QString(*NameFunction)(), 
    const ContentType& (Invokee::* Getter)() const> 
struct Field;
```

Partial template specialization is not supported for function templates, so the next step is to make a dummy struct. You can actually deduce everything we need from the fields, so the fields are the only necessary type parameters:

```cpp
template <typename... Fields>
struct ObjectSerializer;
```

Now, it gets fun. Turn each parameter of `Field` into a parameter pack, and expand them to get the specialized type:

```cpp
template <
    typename Invokee,
    typename... ContentType, 
    const QString(*...NameFunction)(), 
    const ContentType& (Invokee::*...Getter)() const>
struct ObjectSerializer<Field<Invokee, ContentType, NameFunction, Getter>...>
{ /* ... */ }
```

In the body of this monstrosity template, use the call operator to define the actual function. The body of this function should set a property of `object` to the value extracted to a field.

Since you can't actually expand a parameter pack into statements, you have you use tricks. I'm going to use the trick from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375089/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-print-a-variadic-parameter-pack-using-stdostream) to hide the statements in an `std::initializer_list`, in such a way that everything but the assignments are constant-folded:

```cpp
constexpr void operator ()(QJsonObject& object, const Invokee& invokee) { 
    void(std::initializer_list<nullptr_t> {
        (void(object[NameFunction()] = (invokee.*Getter)()), nullptr)...
    });
}
```

And then you can wrap the whole thing in a convenience function to hide the struct. I rearranged it a bit from yours so `Invokee` is deduced from the argument:

```
template <typename... Fields, typename Invokee>
void serializeToObject(QJsonObject& object, const Invokee& invokee) {
    ObjectSerializer<Fields...>{}(object, invokee);
}
```

After that, tryItOut() will work like you expect:

```cpp
  serializeToObject<
      Field<Data, QString, stringName, &Data::string>
  >(object, data);
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/kHTmPE

#### Simplified C++17 Solution

If C++17 is available to you, you can actually make this a bit nicer by using auto non-type template deduction. For the field, use `auto` in place of the getter, and get rid of the details:

```cpp
template <const QString(*NameFunction)(), auto Getter>
class Field;
```

But when you partially specialize, you can still deduce all that information. You can also use fold expressions to simplify the "expand assignment" trick:

```cpp
template <
    typename Invokee,
    typename... ContentType, 
    const QString(*...NameFunction)(), 
    const ContentType& (Invokee::*...Getter)() const>
struct ObjectSerializer<Field<NameFunction, Getter>...> {
    template <typename TInvokee = Invokee>
    constexpr void operator ()(QJsonObject& object, const Invokee& invokee) {
        (void(object[NameFunction()] = (invokee.*Getter)()), ...);
    }
};
```

So now, `serializeToObject` only needs two template arguments per field instead of 4:

```cpp
  serializeToObject<
      Field<stringName, &Data::string>
  >(object, data);
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/UDinyi

Works find in clang. But ouch, this causes gcc to explode ([bug 92969](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92969)):

```
during RTL pass: expand
<source>: In function 'void serializeToObject(QJsonObject&, const Invokee&) [with Fields = {Field<stringName, &Data::string>}; Invokee = Data]':
<source>:34:34: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
   34 |     ObjectSerializer<Fields...>{}(object, invokee);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Please submit a full bug report,
```

(I *will* send a full bug report shortly)

#### Simplified C++17 Solution (with gcc workaround)

That gcc bug sucks, but it can be worked around by using a different type to serialize each field:

```cpp
template <typename Field>
struct FieldSerializer;

template <typename Invokee, typename ContentType, const QString(*NameFunction)(), const ContentType& (Invokee::*Getter)() const> 
struct FieldSerializer<Field<NameFunction, Getter>>{
    void operator()(QJsonObject& object, const Invokee& invokee) {
        object[NameFunction()] = (invokee.*Getter)();
    }  
};

template <typename... Fields, typename Invokee>
void serializeToObject(QJsonObject& object, const Invokee& invokee) {
    (void(FieldSerializer<Fields>{}(object, invokee)), ...);
}
```

That generates more types than you'd probaby like, but not as many types as, say, a recursive solution.

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/kMYBAy

---

EDITs: I've revised this answer a few times, first to add the C++17 simplification, and later to switch to a non-recursive solution that hopefully has better compile times.

Comment: That's grand. I'd like to buy you a beer good sir, this opens up a lot of other template shenanigans I am sure to try out. I think the compiler might generate a lot of intermediate structs for this though.

Comment: Right, all recursive solutions involve a typesplosion that has a pretty negative effect on compilation. It would be better if you could just expand the parameter packs or use a fold exprssion, but I didn't think you could expand a partial specialization. But I'll be a monkey's uncle: https://godbolt.org/z/E-vDAQ ... on clang. It made gcc segfault! So woohoo, I get to file a bug report.

Comment: Ok, I revised the solution to add a non-recursive solution, as well as a workaround for the gcc bug I found.