# Specializing macro with arguments

Tags: c++, variadic-macros

Suppose I have the following macro:

```
#define LOG(L, ...) func(L, __VA_ARGS__);
```

Where L can be one of `INFO, WARN, FATAL`

Now I want to define it for `FATAL` differently.

```
#define LOG(FATAL, ...) {func(FATAL, __VA_ARGS__); exit(-1);}
```

How to accomplish this?

Edit:
As a follow up to above, is there a better way to do it? i.e. by avoiding macros for example.

Comment: It would be better to select one language tag according to the language you are using

Comment: Any reason to actually use a macro, and not a variadic template?

Comment: @flowit No reason actually. Let me modify the question. Can you put an answer how variadic templates are to be used and why they are better?

Comment: You can check on fatal in the func and return/exit. Make it a template argument with if constexpr if you want to squeeze performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros are mostly a bad choice in C++ – essentially because of they are namespace agnostic and may take effect where it is unexpected.

That said – a sample for how OPs issue could be solved e.g. using [token pasting](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators):

```
#include <iostream>

#define LOG(LEVEL, ...) LOG_##LEVEL(__VA_ARGS__)

#define LOG_INFO(...) log(Info, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_WARN(...) log(Warn, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_FATAL(...) do { log(Error, __VA_ARGS__); std::cerr << "Program aborted!\n"; } while (false)

enum Level { Info, Warn, Error };

void log(Level level, const char *text)
{
  static const char *levelText[] = { "INFO", "WARNING", "ERROR" };
  std::cerr << levelText[level] << ": " << text << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  LOG(INFO, "Everything fine. :-)");
  LOG(WARN, "Not so fine anymore. :-|");
  LOG(FATAL, "Things became worst. :-(");
}
```

Output:

```
INFO: Everything fine. :-)
WARNING: Not so fine anymore. :-|
ERROR: Things became worst. :-(
Program aborted!
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/416afc98067386c7)

---

Another sample for the follow-up question - with variadic templates instead of macros:

```
#include <iostream>

enum Level { Info, Warn, Error, Fatal };

template <typename ...ARGS>
void log(Level level, ARGS&& ... args)
{
  static const char *levelText[] = { "INFO", "WARNING", "ERROR", "FATAL" };
  std::cerr << levelText[level] << ": ";
  (std::cerr << ... << args);
  std::cerr << '\n';
  if (level == Fatal) std::cerr << "Program aborted!";
}

int main()
{
  log(Info, "Everything fine.", ' ', ":-)");
  log(Warn, "Not so fine anymore.", ' ', ":-|");
  log(Error, "Things became bad.", ' ', ":-(");
  log(Fatal, "Things became worst.", ' ', "XXX");
}
```

Output:

```
INFO: Everything fine. :-)
WARNING: Not so fine anymore. :-|
ERROR: Things became bad. :-(
FATAL: Things became worst. XXX
Program aborted!
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b8cf99c1c9c1661)

I must admit that I needed some help for the parameter unpacking – found here:
[**SO: What is the easiest way to print a variadic parameter pack using std::ostream?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43783264/7478597).

Comment: Yep. I see why variadic templates is the way to go :)

Answer (score 2):

Extending Scheffs answer a bit, this one passes the log level as a template argument, allowing the use of `if constexpr` (as JVApen mentioned in his comment). You'd need to know the respective level for each log output at compile time, but I think that won't be an issue.

```
enum Level { Info, Warn, Error, Fatal };

template<Level L, typename ...ARGS>
void log(ARGS&& ... args)
{
    static const char *levelText[] = { "INFO", "WARNING", "ERROR", "FATAL" };
    std::cerr << levelText[L] << ": ";
    (std::cerr << ... << args);
    std::cerr << '\n';
    if constexpr (L == Fatal)
        std::cerr << "Program aborted\n";
}
```