# Parameter pack expansion not compiling in c++

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

In c++, when I try to expand a parameter pack, it gives me the errors

> "parameter packs not expanded with '...'" and
>   "error: expected ';' before '...' token"

Help would be very appreciated. I use mingw 8.2.0.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class... Types>
class Test {
    Test(Types... args) {
        cout << args... << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test<string, int> test("this is a test", 3);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the easiest way to print a variadic parameter pack using std::ostream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375089/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-print-a-variadic-parameter-pack-using-stdostream)

Comment: Expansions don't use `<<` as delimiters.  You need a fold expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way makes `std::cout.operator<< (oneoperand)` be `std::cout.operator<<( operand1, operand2, ...)`. You should use a thing like the following

```
template <class... Types>
struct Test {
    Test(const Types &... args) {

        (std::cout << ... << args) << std::endl;
    }
};
```