# GCC compiler error on generic variadic lambda

Tags: gcc, lambda, variadic

For ridiculous reasons, I need the following [generic variadic lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885893/how-to-create-a-variadic-generic-lambda) function. GCC 5.3.0 on MINGW-w64 is rejecting it. `column` is a function template.

```
auto col = [&run](auto&&... params){return column(run,params);}; //error
```

Diagnostics:

```
..\src\RunOutputData.cpp: In lambda function:
..\src\RunOutputData.cpp:94:64: error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':
  auto col = [&run](auto&&... params){return column(run,params);};
                                                                ^
..\src\RunOutputData.cpp:94:64: note:         'params'
```

[Is](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41934) [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47226) [wrong](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68071)?

Comment: `template<class CT> auto run_col(Run<CT>const&run){return [&](auto&&... params){
 return column(run,std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...);};}` instantiated with `auto col = run_col(run);` appears to work. Also `auto col = [&run](auto&&... p){return column(run,std::forward<decltype(p)>(p)...);};` appears to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `col` lambda you are using a [parameter pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) but you are not expanding it.

One of solutions to your problem is expanding it inside the parenthesis with parameters to `column` (granted it is defined and will accept the parameters that you pass to it) so that `column` will be called with all the parameters contained in `params...`

```
auto col = [&run](auto&&... params)
{
    return column(run, params...);
};
```

or with perfect forwarding as you've done it:

```
auto col = [&run](auto&&... params)
{
    return column(run, std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...);
};
```