# How to understand destructor of scoped_lock?Does cppreference make a mistake?

Tags: c++, c++17, scoped-lock

```
 ~scoped_lock()
  { std::apply([](auto&... __m) { (__m.unlock(), ...); }, _M_devices); }
```

How to understand `[](auto&... __m) { (__m.unlock(), ...);`? I don't understand the `...` in lambda and I don't know how this implement release mutexes in reverse order.

Just as @HolyBlackCat say,
`(__m.unlock(), ...)` means `(__m1.unlock(),(__m2.unlock(), (__m3.unlock(), (...))))`, but it does not implement unlocking in reverse order.

In cppreference.com :

> When control leaves the scope in which the scoped_lock object was created, the scoped_lock is destructed and the mutexes are released, in reverse order.

I make an experiment to confirm this as follows:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

class mymutex : public std::mutex {
 public:
   void lock() {
     std::mutex::lock();
     std::cout << "mutex " << _i << " locked" << std::endl;
   }
  mymutex(int i): _i(i){}
   bool try_lock() {
    bool res = std::mutex::try_lock();
    if (res) {
      std::cout << "mutex " << _i << " try locked" << std::endl;
    }
    return res;
   }
  void unlock() {
    std::mutex::unlock();
    std::cout << "mutex " << _i << " unlocked" << std::endl;
  }
 private:
  int _i;
};

class Speaking {
 private:
  int a;
  mymutex my1;
  mymutex my2;
  mymutex my3;

public:
  Speaking() : a(0), my1(1), my2(2), my3(3){};
  ~Speaking() = default;
  void speak_without_lock();
  void speak_with_three_lock();
};

void Speaking::speak_without_lock() {
  std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": " << a << std::endl;
  a++;
}

void Speaking::speak_with_three_lock() 
{
  std::scoped_lock<mymutex, mymutex, mymutex> scoped(my1, my2, my3);
  speak_without_lock();
}

int main() {
  Speaking s;

  s.speak_with_three_lock();

  return 0;
}
```

```
mutex 1 locked
mutex 2 try locked
mutex 3 try locked
1: 0
mutex 1 unlocked
mutex 2 unlocked
mutex 3 unlocked
```

So does cppreference make a mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to create a variadic generic lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25885893/11082165), and also related: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Comment: The first `...` creates a "variadic lambda". The second one creates a "fold expression".

Comment: What code are you quoting to say that they’re not unlocked in reverse order?

Comment: @DavisHerring The experiment I did confirmed this. In the experiment, they were locked in the order of 1 2 3 and unlocked in the order of 1 2 3.

Comment: @xiaowangzhixiao: That’s a good point, but it doesn’t say where this code is.  Maybe you don’t mean to ask about any particular implementation?

Comment: @DavisHerring I use g++ 11.1 . Do you mean this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that cppreference.com is incorrect in this detail. C++17 says:

> ~scoped_lock();
>
> Effects: For all i in [0, sizeof...(MutexTypes)), get(pm).unlock()

which implies that the locks are released in the same order they were taken.

Note that to prevent deadlock, releasing locks in the reverse order of acquiring them is not necessary - it's only necessary to always acquire them in the same order.