# C++ template pack deduction - What am I doing wrong in this example?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic, type-deduction

This compiles and works fine:

```
template<typename T, typename ... Args>
void func()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    func<Args...>();
}

int main()
{
    func<int, char, float>();
    return 0;
}
```

...and this also compiles and works fine:

```
struct Object {};   // Some dummy object

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
void func(Object *a)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    func<Args...>(a);
}

int main()
{
    Object *a = new Object;
    func<int, char, float>(a);
    return 0;
}
```

...but this does NOT compile, because it cannot resolve T:

```
struct Object {};   // Some dummy object

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
void func(Object *a, Object *b)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    func<Args...>(a, b);
}

int main()
{
    Object *a = new Object;
    Object *b = new Object;
    func<int, char, float>(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Sorry for not being able to put on Ideone, blocked from work.

Comment: None of these example compile on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea051afe36f710d1

Comment: Strange... I agree with you, but I am using Clang 3.7 on my OS X laptop and it compiles fine.  Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @NathanOliver, your code does not compile neither using [clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/q01EDQ5YCAl4Mr5l) nor using [gcc](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/EnpoffHPYBh0vUYF).

The following functions get instantiated:

```
func<int, char, float>()
func<char, float>()
func<float>()
```

Now, the parameter pack is empty, and the compiler tries to instantiate `func<>` which leads to the error that the template argument `T` cannot be deduced.

In order to end the recursion properly, you can use one of the answers of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124969/recursive-variadic-template-to-print-out-the-contents-of-a-parameter-pack), e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Last>
void func()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template<typename First, typename Second, typename ... Args>
void func()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    func<Second, Args...>();
}

int main()
{
    func<int, char, float>();
    return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>live example</kbd>](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JPKSYqEoNxh2K8yo)

**output**

```
void func() [First = int, Second = char, Args = <float>]
void func() [First = char, Second = float, Args = <>]
void func() [Last = float]
```