# How to fill array with contents of a template parameter pack?

Tags: c++, recursion, c++14, variadic-templates, compile-time

I had nested partially specialized template code working with VS 2015 until I discovered that [it was not standards-compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3052579/2747466). I want it to be so I twisted my code to overcome the former issue and also [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2114807) and have now hit a hard wall.

Using variadic templates and partial specialization I would like to fill an array at compile-time given a fixed set of parameters.

What I want to achieve also seems similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7128003/2747466) but I did not manage to make it work.

Consider the following program:

```
#include <cstdlib>

template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
struct Array;

template <typename T, std::size_t Size, std::size_t Iteration, typename ...Args>
struct ArrayFiller {
    inline
    static void fill(Array<T, Size>& a, const Args&... args) {
        ArrayFiller<T, Size, Iteration, Args...>::fill_recursive(a, args...);
    }

    inline
    static void fill_recursive(Array<T, Size>& a, const T& i, const Args&... args) {
        a.data[Size - Iteration - 1] = i;
        ArrayFiller<T, Size, Iteration - 1>::fill_recursive(a, args...);
    }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
struct ArrayFiller<T, Size, 0> {
    inline
    static void fill_recursive(Array<T, Size>& a, const T& i) {
        a.data[Size - 1] = i;
    }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
struct Array {
    T data[Size];

    template <typename ...Args>
    Array(const Args&... args) {
        ArrayFiller<T, Size, Size - 1, Args...>::fill(*this, args...);
    }
};

int main() {
    Array<int, 2> c(42, -18);
    return 0;
}
```

...and the beginning of its `g++ -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra` output (as of version 5.3.0):

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘static void ArrayFiller<T, Size, Iteration, Args>::fill(Array<T, Size>&, const Args& ...) [with T = int; long unsigned int Size = 2ul; long unsigned int Iteration = 1ul; Args = {int, int}]’:
main.cpp:34:54:   required from ‘Array<T, Size>::Array(const Args& ...) [with Args = {int, int}; T = int; long unsigned int Size = 2ul]’
main.cpp:39:28:   required from here
main.cpp:10:65: error: no matching function for call to ‘ArrayFiller<int, 2ul, 1ul, int, int>::fill_recursive(Array<int, 2ul>&, const int&, const int&)’
         ArrayFiller<T, Size, Iteration, Args...>::fill_recursive(a, args...);
                                                                 ^
main.cpp:14:17: note: candidate: static void ArrayFiller<T, Size, Iteration, Args>::fill_recursive(Array<T, Size>&, const T&, const Args& ...) [with T = int; long unsigned int Size = 2ul; long unsigned int Iteration = 1ul; Args = {int, int}]
     static void fill_recursive(Array<T, Size>& a, const T& i, const Args&... args) {
                 ^
main.cpp:14:17: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 3 provided
```

Basically the compiler complains that there is no matching function because from what I understand the parameter pack is expanded either too "soon" or too "late" in my logic: the `const T& i` argument in the recursive call messes up the expansion.

**How would you fix it?**

I am also interested in alternate / better / cleaner solutions.

Comment: Why do you need variadic template,  when constexpr constructor with initializer list would do?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why you're not just using `std::array`, which supports precisely this syntax... This isn't "filling" an array, which implies generating values; it's just initialising it from values provided. And when the C++ Standard Library has already provided the wheel you seemingly need, it's usually a bad idea to try to reinvent it yourself.

Comment: @SergeyA: could you please elaborate? Is it what Vittorio's answer is about? Sorry I'm not as comfortable with C++ as with other tools.

Comment: @underscore_d: well, this is a minimal example for SO but basically the real use case offers more bloa...functionality than just holding some values together.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is a solution not based on template recursion acceptable in your use case? [wandbox link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/AgjhHieuh9tj2TmU)

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
struct Array {
    T data[Size];

    template <typename ...Args>
    constexpr Array(const Args&... args) : data{args...} {

    }
};

int main() {
    Array<int, 2> c(42, -18);
    assert(c.data[0] == 42);
    assert(c.data[1] == -18);

    constexpr Array<int, 2> cc(42, -18);
    static_assert(cc.data[0] == 42);
    static_assert(cc.data[1] == -18);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vittorio, this has been an eye opener. I added a public setter that simply does `*this = Array(args...);` to fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I might be off target here but based on this requirement "... I would like to fill an array at compile-time given a fixed set of parameters." and this code:

```
int main() {
Array<int, 2> c(42, -18);
return 0;
}
```

I have been left wondering is this not solvable with a normal array declaration and initialization?

```
    int main() {
        constexpr  int c []{42, -18};
        static_assert( c[0] == 42 ) ;
        // and so on
      return 0;
    }
```

In a comment to the previous answer, you are mentioning some setter? There must be something missing in here... In case you need to have this class `Array` as above, perhaps the simplest way to do so is this:

```
template<typename T, T ... V >
struct Array
{
  constexpr static T data_[]{ V... };
  // not strictly necessary
  constexpr static size_t size{ sizeof(data_) / sizeof(T) };
};
```

Usage is this:

```
  // length is not required for declaration
  using int_array_of_4 = Array<int,1,2,3,4> ;
  static_assert( int_array_of_4::data_[0] == 1) ;
  // and so on
```

But I might be barking on the wrong tree here?