# constexpr union with POD Struct members using parameter pack expansions

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, constexpr, unions

I am trying construct a **constexpr union** which wraps 3 types.  The union can contain a raw uint8_t `array` or fixed length arrays of `PODTypeA` or `PODTypeB`.  The lengths of these arrays are known at compile time and given by constexpr values.

The POD structures are very simple:

```
struct PODTypeA {
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

or

```
struct PODTypeB {
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
};
```

The embedded environment does not have the standard template library available.  As such, I cannot use the `constexpr std::array<T,N>` which would make things a lot easier.

Shown below is a `constexpr Array(const Args&... args)` array implementation, which should function as a constexpr data member to hold array fields.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
struct Array {
    T data[Size];
    template <typename ...Args>
    constexpr Array(const Args&... args)
        : data{ args... }
    {}
};
```

I don't fully understand how the parameter pack expansion works (effectively memcpy(ing) the array via the compiler to the specified union member).  If someone could explain that it would be a plus.  I found the above Array template parameter pack expander in the checked answer to the following stack overlflow **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169965/how-to-fill-array-with-contents-of-a-template-parameter-pack)** (where there is also a live example).

I put this in a **[coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/238a6d3c4b61bd2f)** project but I am having lots of compile issues.

I have 3 constructors for the union, each one of these takes a fixed length array parameter as follows:

```
constexpr static auto gSizeBytes = 2048;
constexpr static int gArraySizeA = 2;
constexpr static int gArraySizeB = 3;

union UnionStruct {

    explicit constexpr UnionStruct(
        const uint8_t(&rParam)[gSizeBytes] = {})
        : byteArray(rParam)
    {}

    explicit constexpr UnionStruct(
        const PODTypeA(&rParam)[gArraySizeA])
        : arrayA(rParam)
    {}

    explicit constexpr UnionStruct(
        const PODTypeB(&rParam)[gArraySizeB])
        : arrayB(rParam)
    {}

    Array<uint8_t, gSizeBytes> byteArray;
    Array<PODTypeA, gArraySizeA> arrayA;
    Array<PODTypeB, gArraySizeB> arrayB;
};
```

And here is how I expect to use it:

```
int main()
{
    PODTypeA[UnionStruct::gArraySizeA] arrayTypeA = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
    // construct union from fixed PODTypeA array with 2 elements
    UnionStruct foo (arrayTypeA);
}
```

The compiler issues the following errors:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr Array<T, Size>::Array(const Args& ...) [with Args = {unsigned char [2048]}; T = unsigned char; long unsigned int Size = 2048]':
main.cpp:34:27:   required from here
main.cpp:12:25: error: invalid conversion from 'const unsigned char*' to 'unsigned char' [-fpermissive]
         : data{ args... }
                         ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr Array<T, Size>::Array(const Args& ...) [with Args = {PODTypeA [2]}; T = PODTypeA; long unsigned int Size = 2]':
main.cpp:39:24:   required from here
main.cpp:12:25: error: invalid conversion from 'const PODTypeA*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr Array<T, Size>::Array(const Args& ...) [with Args = {PODTypeB [3]}; T = PODTypeB; long unsigned int Size = 3]':
main.cpp:44:24:   required from here
main.cpp:12:25: error: invalid conversion from 'const PODTypeB*' to 'uint32_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-fpermissive]
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:54:14: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
     PODTypeA[2] arrayTypeA = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
              ^
main.cpp:54:14: error: expected ']' before numeric constant
     PODTypeA[2] arrayTypeA = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
              ^
              ]
main.cpp:54:13: error: structured binding declaration cannot have type 'PODTypeA'
     PODTypeA[2] arrayTypeA = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
             ^
main.cpp:54:13: note: type must be cv-qualified 'auto' or reference to cv-qualified 'auto'
main.cpp:54:13: error: empty structured binding declaration
main.cpp:54:17: error: expected initializer before 'arrayTypeA'
     PODTypeA[2] arrayTypeA = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
                 ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:56:22: error: 'arrayTypeA' was not declared in this scope
     UnionStruct foo (arrayTypeA);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:56:22: note: suggested alternative: 'gArraySizeA'
     UnionStruct foo (arrayTypeA);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~
                      gArraySizeA
main.cpp:54:13: warning: unused structured binding declaration [-Wunused-variable]
     PODTypeA[2] arrayTypeA = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
             ^
```

Comment: Int `byteArray(rParam)`, you are attempting to initialiize `byteArray.data[0]` with `rParam`. The former is `unsigned char`, the latter is `unsigned char*`. Hence the first error.

Comment: Array declaration goes like this: `PODTypeA arrayTypeA[UnionStruct::gArraySizeA]`. You have the bound in the wrong place.