# Variadic Template Recursion

Tags: c++11, templates, recursion, variadic-templates, variadic

I am trying to use recursion to solve this problem where if i call

```
decimal<0,0,1>();
```

i should get the decimal number (4 in this case).

I am trying to use recursion with variadic templates but cannot get it to work.

Here's my code;

```
template<>
int decimal(){
    return 0;
}



template<bool a,bool...pack>
int decimal(){
        cout<<a<<"called"<<endl;
        return a*2 + decimal<pack...>();
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    cout<<decimal<0,0,1>()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recursive variadic template to print out the contents of a parameter pack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124969/recursive-variadic-template-to-print-out-the-contents-of-a-parameter-pack)

Comment: When asking "why does this code not work, and how do I fix it", include error messages (what went wrong) as well as what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename = void>
int decimal(){
    return 0;
}

template<bool a,bool...pack>
int decimal(){
        cout<<a<<"called"<<endl;
        return a + 2*decimal<pack...>();
};
```

The problem was with the recursive case, where it expects to be able to call `decltype<>()`. That is what I have defined in the first overload above. You can essentially ignore the `typename=void`, the is just necessary to allow the first one to compile.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be the use of a constexpr function (so you can use it's values it's value run-time, when appropriate) where the values are argument of the function.

Something like

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int decimal ()
 { return 0; }

template <typename T, typename ... packT>
constexpr int decimal (T const & a, packT ... pack)
 { return a*2 + decimal(pack...); }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
   constexpr  int  val { decimal(0, 0, 1) };

   static_assert( val == 2, "!");

   std::cout << val << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

But I obtain 2, not 4.

Are you sure that your code should return 4?

**-- EDIT --**

As pointed by aschepler, my example `decimal()` template function return "eturns twice the sum of its arguments, which is not" what do you want.

Well, with `0`, `1`, `true` and `false` you obtain the same; with other number, you obtain different results.

But you can modify `decimal()` as follows

```
template <typename ... packT>
constexpr int decimal (bool a, packT ... pack)
 { return a*2 + decimal(pack...); }
```

to avoid this problem.

Comment: This returns twice the sum of its arguments, which is not what's wanted.

Comment: @aschepler - you're right; my intention was to make a more flexible function but should be explained. Modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a C++14 solution.  It is mostly C++11, except for `std::integral_sequence` nad `std::index_sequence`, both of which are relatively easy to implement in C++11.

```
template<bool...bs>
using bools = std::integer_sequence<bool, bs...>;

template<std::uint64_t x>
using uint64 = std::integral_constant< std::uint64_t, x >;

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr uint64< ((std::uint64_t)1) << (std::uint64_t)N > bit{};

template<std::uint64_t... xs>
struct or_bits : uint64<0> {};

template<std::int64_t x0, std::int64_t... xs>
struct or_bits<x0, xs...> : uint64<x0 | or_bits<xs...>{} > {};

template<bool...bs, std::size_t...Is>
constexpr
uint64<
  or_bits<
    uint64<
      bs?bit<Is>:std::uint64_t(0)
    >{}...
  >{}
>
from_binary( bools<bs...> bits, std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
  (void)bits; // suppress warning
  return {};
}


template<bool...bs>
constexpr
auto from_binary( bools<bs...> bits={} )
-> decltype( from_binary( bits, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(bs)>{} ) )
{ return {}; }
```

It generates the resulting value as a type with a `constexpr` conversion to scalar.  This is slightly more powerful than a `constexpr` function in its "compile-time-ness".

It assumes that the first bit is the most significant bit in the list.

You can use `from_binary<1,0,1>()` or `from_binary( bools<1,0,1>{} )`.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2e3967ba295bf05).

This particular style of type-based programming results in code that does all of its work in its signature.  The bodies consist of `return {};`.