# Variadic template function with no arguments

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, variadic-templates, specialization

I want to write a function that will do an operation based on the types, not arguments, of a function. As such, the function receives no template based arguments. The general gist is something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void func() {
    std::cout<<"End marker\n";
}

template <typename Type, typename... T>
void func() {
    std::cout<<"Type sizeof "<<sizeof(T)<<"\n";

    func<T...>();
}

int main() {
    func<int, int, int>();
}
```

Which, of course, doesn't compile. I've tried doing this:

```
template <typename Type, typename... T>
void func() {
    std::cout<<"Type sizeof "<<sizeof(T)<<"\n";

    if( sizeof...(T)!=0 )
        func<T...>();
}
```

This does not work, however. The `func<T...>` may not get evaluated, but it does need to be compilable.

Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: `if constexpr`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [recursive variadic template to print out the contents of a parameter pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124969/recursive-variadic-template-to-print-out-the-contents-of-a-parameter-pack)

Comment: @Quentin, yes, thank you. However, this does not solve the generic case. I need to define a function that will be called with `func<>()`, or this will fail in other ways.

Comment: @user1810087 in the sense that "it can't be done with functions", then yes, it does :-(. I already have a struct based implementation. It is _considerably_ more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your original setup work by making `func` a "template function" (that doesn't actually use the template) like:

```cpp
template<int = 0>
void func() {
    std::cout<<"End marker\n";
}

template <typename Type, typename... T>
void func() {
    std::cout<<"Type sizeof "<<sizeof(Type)<<"\n";

    func<T...>();
}
```

And your second one can work by using `if constexpr`, so `func<>()` isn't compiled.

Comment: This always outputs `4`? Look [here](https://godbolt.org/z/VYv24J)

Comment: @NutCracker I assume they wanted the size of each type (Rather than a weird `std::integer_sequence`). `func<char, char[2], char[3]>();` outputs 1, 2, 3 for example.

Comment: Hmm, in that case, question is not properly defined

Answer (score 1):

You can make the non-template function `func` into a variadic template function which accepts zero template arguments. Then let SFINAE move away this template function when the number of arguments is not zero.

Following should work:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Ts) == 0>::type func() {
    std::cout<<"End marker\n";
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
void func() {
    std::cout << "Type sizeof " << sizeof(T) << "\n";

    func<Ts...>();
}

int main() {
    func<int, int, int>();
}
```

However, please note that:

> (8) The validity of a template may be checked prior to any
>   instantiation. [ Note: Knowing which names are type names allows the
>   syntax of every template to be checked in this way. — end note ] The
>   program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if: [..] (8.3) every
>   valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template
>   parameter pack...

Source [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.res#8.3)

**UPDATE**

This would work too:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

void func() {
    std::cout<<"End marker\n";
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
void func() {
    std::cout << "Type sizeof " << sizeof(T) << "\n";

    if constexpr (0 == sizeof...(Ts))
        func();
    else
        func<Ts...>();
}

int main() {
    func<int, int, int>();
}
```

Comment: `template <typename... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Ts) == 0>::type func()` make the template pedantically ill formed: *"The program is ill-formed,
no diagnostic required, if:
(8.3) — every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack,"*.

Comment: @Jarod42 tnx for that. I will update my answer with this note.

Answer (score 1):

With fold-expression (in C++17), you might do:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void func()
{
    ((std::cout << "Type sizeof " << sizeof(Ts) << "\n"), ...);
    std::cout << "End marker\n";
}
```

That can even be done in C++11, but it would be more verbose:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void func()
{
    const int dummy[] = {((std::cout << "Type sizeof " << sizeof(Ts) << "\n"), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable.
    std::cout <<"End marker\n";
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9653055a711a9b91)