# How to create function-template, that expands parameter-pack which doesn't represent function argument(s)?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I apologize, but I had a big problem in expressing the case in one sentence of the title.

The problem:
I have a class template based on many "properties" (don't take this "property" keyword too literally):

```
template<typename ... P>
class C: public P... {}
```

Then I want separate, free function template that takes two instances and performs some call for each "property":

```
template<typename ... P>
void foo(C<P> &c1, C<P> &c2)
{
    { doSomething<p>()... }      // for each type p in pack P
}

template<typename T>
void doSomething() {}
```

The problem is that P doesn't represent a set of my function arguments. Instead it parametrizes argument types. So I don't know how to write "expansion". 
Is such thing possible at all?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. Could you show an example of how you want to use this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [recursive variadic template to print out the contents of a parameter pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124969/recursive-variadic-template-to-print-out-the-contents-of-a-parameter-pack). This should at least give you an idea of something you could do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you are just missing the parameter pack expansion in the function parameters. Then there is also a small typo (`p`->`P`) and you seem to intend to use a fold-expression to execute the function for all types which has a slightly different syntax:

```
template<typename ... P>
void foo(C<P...> &c1, C<P...> &c2)
{
    // Parentheses and comma required to signify fold expression using the comma operator
    ( doSomething<P>(), ... ); 
}
```

I also feel like you would want to pass `c1` and `c2` on to `doSomething` (which probably should be taking he objects as `T&`, I guess?), otherwise that function will depend only on the type, not an actual object of that type.

Comment: True! Thanks a lot for this